# Best approach getting answer from multiplay text boxes

Tags: swift, xcode

I've created multiple text fields where each text field accepts only 1 character and then moves to the next box. I would like to check users answer when all the text fields are filled but I'm a bit confused as to how to do so.

My first approach was to create an answer String and every time textFieldDidChange is called I add to the String the textfield.text but how can I know when all the boxes been filled and call the checkAnswer function another issue is that if the user decides to fill the boxes in a different order then when I compare the user answer to the correct answer it obviously comes incorrect as the order is different.

[here's a pic of the boxes [every game round it generates a different number of boxes depending on the answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37Z8X.png)

Comment: As you say your textField holds one 1 character. You can easily check if all the fields are filled or not by comparing `yourAnswerString.count == numberOfTextFields` you have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know how many number of textFields you have then, you can add a property observer to `yourAnswerString` and as soon as the value of `yourAnswerString` becomes equal to `numberOfTextFields`, it will call the check Answer function automatically.

```
var yourAnswerString = "" { 
    didSet { 
        if yourAnswerString.count == numberOfTextFields {
            self.checkAnswer()
        }
    }
}
```